# iOS7, Instruments device automation and alert block never not always called.target.frontMostApp().alert().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[0].tap();

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, instruments

I have an app which pop up's an alert right after app loads. To handle this app, I have code like this[After trying all possibilities]. My alert is like this, Alert->tableview,cells.
Code is:

```
target.frontMostApp().alert().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["Ok"].tap();
```

Issues I am facing are:
1. Alert block not always being called
2. If more than 1 alerts are encountered, only for the first time, alert will be handled.

Please help me. Below is my sample code.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
target.delay(5);

function test_status(){
 if (1<2){
 UIALogger.logMessage("Test pass");
 target.delay(2);
 UIALogger.logPass(testName);
 } else {
    UIALogger.logMessage("Test Failed");
    UIALogger.logFail(testName);
    UIALogger.logFail(testName);
}
}

function play_titles(){
UIALogger.logMessage("Tapping on play movie");
window.buttons()["Play Movie"].tap();
target.delay(5);
}

UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
var title = alert.name();
UIALogger.logMessage("Encountred::"+title);
alert.logElementTree();
var alert_1 = "string";
if ( title == "string"){
        UIALogger.logWarning("Alert with title '"+title+"' encountred. Pressed 'OK'.");
        //target.frontMostApp().alert().defaultButton().tap();
        //target.frontMostApp().alert().buttons()["Ok"].tap();
            target.frontMostApp().alert().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[0].tap();
        target.delay(5);
        return true;
}   
return false;
}



var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
var testName = "diagnoser app launch";

//target.pushTimeout(5);

UIALogger.logStart("Test case::"+testName);
target.logElementTree()
target.delay(5);
//target.popTimeout();
var table = target.frontMostApp().alert().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[0].name();
UIALogger.logMessage("Table Buttons name::"+table);
var names = target.frontMostApp().alert().defaultButton()[1];
UIALogger.logMessage("Buttons name::"+names);
//target.frontMostApp().alert().buttons()["Ok"].tap();
play_titles();
target.deactivateAppForDuration(5);
target.delay(5);
//target.frontMostApp().alert().buttons()["Ok"].tap(); 
// No alert block is called
test_status();
```